# ver slow connection between VNC server on MacOSX and client on Windows 7 

Tags: vnc

I'm running Windows 7 and I want to VNC into my Macbook.

I've modified the sharing settings appropriately.

However, running VNC is extremely slow (the machines are right next to each other).

- Suggestions for making it faster?
- Or alternative clients?
- Also, is it possible to adjust the resolution size for the viewer?

  I am currently using TightVNC Viewer

Comment: Which client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Vine Server is it's own VNC server that lets you make adjustments that the built in vnc server doesn't without delving into the kickstart script (in ARD Agent). This may be what you are looking for. We use the VNC server from Vine Server and have very good refresh rates.

I've found TightVNC is the best viewer on a PC for controlling the Mac. Response and refresh works best with maxdepth at 32 on your viewer.

Info on kickstart:  http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=RemoteDesktop/3.0/en/ARDC882.html